# mysql_query and apply_filters('post_content', $post->post_content)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in PHP/Wordpress. I was trying to call post_content from a WP DB and after several tries I was finally able to get it to work, however the paragraphs were gone. This is what I was using;

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE id=$id");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['post_content'];
  }
```

I've then changed it to;

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE id=$id");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
  }
```

I am now able to see it as I see on WP, however the post_content doesn't match the $id, the title does as well as the data, but the content is always echoing other post.

I apologize if the explanation is confusing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to be writing a SQL query, Wordpress has [built in query functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). Here's a better way:

```
<?php
$id = 1
$result_post = get_post($id);
echo $result_post->post_content;
?>
```

For more information, I urge you to take a look at [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)'s documentation.

Comment: Is working, the paragraphs and line breaks are missing though, in Mysql the text is just fine... I will see if I can find what I am doing wrong. Thanks for your help Anthony.

Comment: @acrognale re >There's no need to be writing a SQL query.  In my case there was since I'm pulling data from an external WP database on the same server.  So your solution does not work for me.